# show and hide table row on click for JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project in ASP and I'm not used to Javascript or Jquery

I found some code that if I click on a row, it will change the color.

I now want to change the display to normal when I click on a row and then hide it if I click on any other row.

What I have so far

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>INFO</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr onclick="changeMe(this);"> 
    <td>INFO</td> 
            <tr class="versionRow" style ="display:none">
                <td>INFO</td>
            </tr>
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

And my script for changing the color.

```
<script>
    var whosChanged = null;

    function changeMe(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
        el.style.color = "#000000";

        if (whosChanged != null) {
            whosChanged.style.backgroundColor = ""
            whosChanged.style.color = ""
        }

        whosChanged = el;
    }
</script>
```

I just want to be able to display the row with the class versionRow when I click on it.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: you want to hide just the one particular row only?

Comment: It's hidden right now. I want to display it when I click the row. So I just don't know how to change the display attribute for it within my script, since I don't have JavaScript experience.

Comment: How can you click it if it's hidden? You're probably looking for el.style.display = 'block'

Comment: The parent tr is still displayed so I can click that right now. The child tr is hidden right now and when I click the parent tr, I want to change the child tr to display.

Comment: right i understand now. i've posted an answer

Comment: And you know that HTML is invalid? There are four elements of which a `tr` is a valid child: `table`, `tbody`, `thead` and `tfoot`. Outside of those elements you've got invalid HTML which the browser may, or may not, attempt to rescue. If it does then you have an unpredictable HTML/DOM structure. Use valid HTML, and then JavaScript gets a whole lot easier, and far more predictable.

Comment: @DavidThomas, I just didn't post the full table. Will edit for you. Still doesn't make JavaScript easier though.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can I ask you to outline, step-by-step, what you want this script to do? Right now I don't understand what you need (though perhaps I'm just tired). I *think* you want to click the `tr` with the `onclick` event handler, and show the hidden `tr.versionRow`?

Comment: Yea, that is exactly what I want. Like I mentioned I just want to change the display from none to block in tr.versionRow when I click the tr with the onclick event. If I change the display:none to display:block manually, it will display the tr.versionRow but I want to change it when someone clicks the tr with the onclick event.

Comment: wait...Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
function hasClass(el, needle) {
    if (!el || !needle) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var classes = el.className.split(/\s+/);
        for (var i = 0, len = classes.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (classes[i] == needle) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

function nextElementSiblingShim(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return el.nextSibling.nodeType == 1 ? el.nextSibling : nextElementSiblingShim(el.nextSibling);
    }
}

function changeMe(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var nextElem = el.nextElementSibling || nextElementSiblingShim(el);
        if (hasClass(nextElem, 'versionRow')) {
            nextElem.style.display = window.getComputedStyle(nextElem, null).display !== 'none' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
        }
    }
}

var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('changeMe');

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = function(){
        changeMe(this);
    };
}​​​​​​
```

This does rely on well-formed HTML, though: as noted in my comment to your question a `tr` is *only* a valid child of a `table`, `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` elements. It is ***not*** a valid child of another `tr`. You could nest a `table` inside of a `td`, but there should be *no elements* inside of a `tr` *except* for `td` and `th`. That said, the following HTML will allow the above script(s) to work:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>INFO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="changeMe">
            <td>INFO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="versionRow">
            <td>INFO</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7Gabh/).

Note that I've taken out the `onclick` event-handlers, to separate the behaviour from the mark-up, and, hopefully, make things more maintainable in future. I've *also* moved the (invalid) nested `tr` from its parent and added it as a sibling.

Comment: Well, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done this without jQuery, try this

```
<script>
    var whosChanged = null;

    function changeMe(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
        el.style.color = "#000000";

        if (whosChanged != null) {
            whosChanged.style.backgroundColor = ""
            whosChanged.style.color = ""
        }

        whosChanged = el;

        // ok so you are using jquery. The above isn't at all!
        // in which case it's so simple
        el.find('.versionRow').show();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I understand the logic but I don't think it's finding the row.

Comment: this is why we use jquery. is it the one row in one table or might there be many tables with these rows?

Comment: I don't think I'm understand what you're saying. It's just the row inside another row. Like I've mentioned in my comments if I just change the display:none to display:block, it will display fine. I just want to be able to change that when they click the row with the onclick event. I know it might sound confusing but I think it makes sense to me.

Comment: it's a row inside another row. if there is only one on the page you'd user getElementById(). If there are many tables that do this that wouldn't work

Comment: updated my answer. I think you are actually using jQuery after all

Comment: Yes and I think the problem was like everyone else described that you can't put a row within a row.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem with this is that you cant add an row within an row. So your browser (at least chrome) make instead of this html part:

```
<tr onclick="changeMe(this);"> 
    <td>INFO</td> 
            <tr class="versionRow" style ="display:none">
                <td>INFO</td>
            </tr>
</tr>
```

This:

```
<tr onclick="changeMe(this);"> 
    <td>INFO</td>
</tr> 
<tr class="versionRow" style ="display:none">
    <td>INFO</td>
</tr>
```

So if you only have one element with the class name versionRow, there should be no problem when you reformat the code like the browser does. All you have to do is to add this line of jquery code:

```
$('.versionRow').css("display","block");
```

But if you want to display the versionBlock of the child wich you clicked you must reformat the html to. It can look like something like this:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>INFO</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr onclick="changeMe(this);" > 
    <td>INFO</td> <td><span style="display:none;" class="versionRow" >INFO</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody> 
</table> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the script will look like this:

```
var whosChanged = null;

    function changeMe(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
        el.style.color = "#000000";

        $('span.versionRow',el).css("display","block");

        if (whosChanged != null) {
            whosChanged.style.backgroundColor = ""
            whosChanged.style.color = ""
        }

        whosChanged = el;
    }​
```

[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ToBadForU/GCQeE/)