# ASP .NET how to onclick hide table row

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I would like to hide one row of the table, when I click on ref.

I have tried something like this:

```
{
    <tr id="trHide1" runat="server">
        <td>@Ajax.ActionLink(r.Jmeno.ToString(), "Detail", new { id = r.Jmeno }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "modalContent", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "openModalWindow" }), @r.Prijmeni</td>
        <td>@r.Rez_kolobezky.Reg_cislo</td>
        <td>@r.Datum_od</td>
        <td>@r.Datum_do</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("OK", "Schovej", "Dnes", new { id = r.Id }, new
                { onclick = "trHide1=false"})</td>
     </tr>
}
```

and method in controler looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Schovej(int id)
{
   try
   {
      Rezervace_dao rd = new Rezervace_dao();
      Rezervace r = rd.GetById(id);
      //var trHide1 = false;
      TempData["message-success"] = "Koloběžka byla odevzdaná";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       throw;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dnes");
}
```

Comment: Why not just use javascript to do it in the client? (and `runat="server"` is webforms code , not mvc)

Comment: Sorry, My Bad! its http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545921/show-and-hide-table-row-on-click-for-jquery

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is:

1. On you ViewModel create a bollean property: ShowRow
2. Set his value on the controller: r.ShowRow = true
3. On your view set on row you want to hide, something like this

{

```
<td @((!r.ShowRow) ? "style='display:none'" : string.Empty)>@r.Datum_do</td>
```

}